# Pandas AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Datetime'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with holt winter method taking [help from here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/02/time-series-forecasting-methods/). My data format is

```
 Year       Rate
0  2013  34.700000
1  2013  34.666667
2  2013  34.600000
3  2014  35.300000
4  2014  34.180000
```

Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd 

#Importing data

df = pd.read_csv('/home/rajnish.kumar/eclipse-workspace/ShivShakti/Result/weeklyDatarateyearonly/part-00000-971f46d7-a97d-4a7e-be41-dc840c2d0618-c000.csv')

df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime,format='%Y')
```

But I am getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Datetime'

Comment: Presumably you don't have a column called `Datetime`. This is why I prefer not to use the . accessor syntax for column names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data is indeed as shown (with columns `Rate` & `Year`), you are referencing a column (`Datetime`) that does not exist (in contrast with the data in the linked blog post, where there is indeed such a column):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Year':[2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014], 'Rate':[34.7, 34.6,34.6,35.3,34.18]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Year", "Rate"])
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime,format='%Y') 
# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Datetime'
```

You should reference `Year` instead:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'],format='%Y') 
df
# result:
   Year   Rate  Timestamp
0  2013  34.70 2013-01-01
1  2013  34.60 2013-01-01
2  2013  34.60 2013-01-01
3  2014  35.30 2014-01-01
4  2014  34.18 2014-01-01
```

Comment: I'd still prefer `df['Year']` over `df.Year`. There's just so many methods in Pandas for it to be confusing on the surface, let alone `AttributeError`s on top

Comment: @roganjosh not a pandas expert, so I'll take your word (edited to `df['Year']`) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Year':[2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014], 'Rate':[34.7, 34.6,34.6,35.3,34.18]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Year", "Rate"])
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Year)
```